# Passing file directly to nano fails with sighup or sigterm

Tags: search, find, edit, nano

was want to search for a specific file on my server and directly edit it within nano.

i tried it like this, but it wont work

```
find -name file.php | xargs nano $1
```

the file is found, but it wont work like that

```
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
```

how to do that proberly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution in using find intern exec function

```
# find -name file.php -exec nano {} \;
```

Comment: This one will execute separate command for each found file, so you will for example lose buffer.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is to use backticks if you have to use other command. It's for example useful with `git status`:

```
nano `git status | grep modified | awk '{ print $2 }'`
```

Or, with find:

```
nano $(find -name file\*.php)
```

Comment: This IS the solution for multiple files. that's why it was posted here.

Comment: Ah, awesome! Thanks, and sorry for replying a year after it was posted.